# Sticky element overlaps absolute element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a page with a sticky navbar and sidebar. Only the content area shouldn't be sticky.

The navbar should have a dropdown button. The problem now is that the sticky sidebar overlaps the dropdown menu. And if the dropdown has multiple items, you can't click on an item.

Is there a way to force the dropdown menu to overlap the sticky sidebar?

```js
var open = false;
function toggle() {
  open = !open;
  if (open) {
    document.getElementById('menu').classList.add('visibile')
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').classList.remove('visibile')
  }
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "navbar navbar" "sidebar content";
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background: #0f0;
  grid-area: navbar;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #00f;
  position: absolute;
}

.visibile {
    display: block !important;
}

.sidebar {
/*   width: 200px; */
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}

.content {
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet);
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="navbar">
    <button onclick="toggle()">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="menu" class="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `z-index: 1;` to the `navbar`. Read more about the [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) CSS property. Consequently, the `navbar` becomes clickable.

See the snippet below.

**Snippet 1:**

```js
var open = false;

function toggle() {
  open = !open;
  if (open) {
    document.getElementById('menu').classList.add('visibile')
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').classList.remove('visibile')
  }
}

/* Added */
const link = document.querySelector("a");
link.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Clicked");
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "navbar navbar" "sidebar content";
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background: #0f0;
  grid-area: navbar;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1; /* Added */
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #00f;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Added */
.menu a {
  color: white;
}

.visibile {
  display: block !important;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}

.content {
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="navbar">
    <button onclick="toggle()">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="menu" class="menu">
      <a href="#">Click me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

##### Additional explanation

Your code is perfect to demonstrate the `z-index`.

If you run *Snippet 1*, open the dropdown and click on the link, you'll see the following:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Now, also add the following CSS:

```
.as-console-wrapper {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

**Snippet 2:**

```js
var open = false;

function toggle() {
  open = !open;
  if (open) {
    document.getElementById('menu').classList.add('visibile')
  } else {
    document.getElementById('menu').classList.remove('visibile')
  }
}

/* Added */
const link = document.querySelector("a");
link.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Clicked");
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "navbar navbar" "sidebar content";
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background: #0f0;
  grid-area: navbar;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1; /* Added */
}

/* Added */
.as-console-wrapper {
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #00f;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Added */
.menu a {
  color: white;
}

.visibile {
  display: block !important;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}

.content {
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet);
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="navbar">
    <button onclick="toggle()">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="menu" class="menu">
      <a href="#">Click me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

If you run *Snippet 2*, open the dropdown and click on the link, you'll see the following:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Why? Because elements with a larger z-index overlap those with a smaller one.

Comment: @ThomasMueller I edited my answer for additional information.